# Testing Google Game Services Auto Match On Unpublished Game (C++)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, apportable

I'm trying to test our implemented of the Real Time Multiplayer (cpp) API on an unpublished Android game. Both users get into individual Waiting Room UIs and then nothing happens (the users dont connect to each other).

This is the implementation

```
gpg::RealTimeRoomConfig config =
    gpg::RealTimeRoomConfig::Builder()
    .SetMinimumAutomatchingPlayers(2)
    .SetMaximumAutomatchingPlayers(8)
    .Create();


m_service->RealTimeMultiplayer().CreateRealTimeRoom(config, this, 
[this](gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::RealTimeRoomResponse const &response) {

       this->m_room = response.room;

        if (gpg::IsSuccess(status))
        {
            m_service->RealTimeMultiplayer().ShowWaitingRoomUI(m_room, 2,
            [this](gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::WaitingRoomUIResponse const &waitResult) {
            // PlayGame() -  We never get here successfully.
            });
        }
});
```

Now from here the waiting rooms do nothing. They dont connect to each other. Each player sits alone in a waiting room.

We have a game published in Google Play Beta and we have a Game Services page with the app linked and real time multiplayer enabled. Both test accounts are on the testers list.

I'm not sure why they won't connect. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Seeing this in the logs:

```
04-13 20:22:26.071 14065 14337 V GamesNativeSDK: Detaching from JVM on thread main_dispatch
04-13 20:22:26.071 14065 14337 V GamesNativeSDK: Didn't detach thread from Java VM: error occurred.
```

Might be relevant to note that we are attempting to use the gpg-cpp sdk in an ios app through the apportable porting system.

EDIT:

Solved. I had to use minimum players as 1.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to include the play services library project in your project. You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid) for the detailed instructions.

You can also refer to these related GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/154
- https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/155